# javascript recursion rewriting with iterative array stack

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, fibonacci

Need a template for rewriting a recursive javascript function as an iterative array stack. For hope that this approach is faster than standard recursion and would use less memory. I use object references as parameters. My function is negascout, but I'd love to reverse engineer the smaller and elegant Fibonacci_sequence.

A Simpler example would be to rewrite Fibonacci_sequence.

From [rosettacode](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence) for Fibonacci_sequence

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
   if (n < 2){
     return 1;
   }else{
     return fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1);
   }
}

console.log(fibonacci(7));
//Returns 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterative way can be:

```js
function iterativeFibonacci(n){
  if (n < 2){
     return 1;
  }

  var i;
  var fibs = new Array();
  fibs.push(0);
  fibs.push(1);
  for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
    fibs.push(fibs[0] + fibs[1]);
    fibs.shift();
  }
  return fibs[0];
}

document.write(iterativeFibonacci(7));
```